# How to use AutiIt to simulate Keystrokes using AutoIt for IME other than English

Tags: windows, scripting, autoit, ime

I am trying to figure out how to simulate keystroke with AutoIt using default IME (Input Method Engine) for Indic (or any other input method).

For example and if I send key as `Send("a")` to Notepad, I should get a character which is on Key 'a' using  IME currently set.
Again If I Send Key M, I should get letter स if IME Hindi/Marathi language and Inscript Keyboard is set.

Currently I am getting same English letter M instead of स.

My Autoit script is as follows

```
$myvar = "`1234567890-=\qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;'©zxcvbnm,./"
$charArray = StringSplit($myvar,"",2)
For $char in $charArray
    Send( $char & "{ENTER}")
Next
```

Can some one tell me how achieve this in above script?

Comment: `send()` doesn't simulate a keypress, but sends a character (ignoring any "keyboard-to-character-translations) Have you tried to `send("स")`?

Comment: This to ensure that if I press  key "m" I am getting "स".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got clue for this problem on Autoit's forum [How Can I Find Non-English Characters' Key Code?](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/138246-virtual-key-code-udf/), there I came across with `DllCall` function call.

So now I have following function call

`DllCall('user32.dll', 'int', 'keybd_event', 'int',$hChar, 'int', 0, 'int', 0, 'ptr', 0)`

I can replace value of $hChar with required key code.
For example if I want to type स with Inscript Keyboard and Devanagari language, I should send 0x4D which is Hex code for the keyboard key m.

To convert character m to key code 0x4D  we will have to write conversion for all keyboard keys.

We can get श with the the same keycode if we send {SHIFTDOWN} before calling this function.

```
$hChar = "0x4D"
Send("{SHIFTDOWN}")
DllCall('user32.dll', 'int', 'keybd_event', 'int', $hChar, 'int', 0, 'int', 0, 'ptr', 0)
Send("{SHIFTUP}")
```

(To use `DllCall` we must include WinAPI.au3 in our Autoit script.)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using clipboard:

- call `ClipPut('string with national characters')`
- and then simulate `Ctrl+V` - `Send('^v')`

If clipboard is not suitable (as in the case of menu accelerators or searching through listview) please tell us what exactly are you trying to send keys to - there may be a way.